# How to share common functionality between two Eclipse plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have two Eclipse refactoring plugins that share quite a bit of functionality and I would like to factor them out. What is the best way to do this in Eclipse? Do I simply create a jar file that I share between the two plugins or do I create a third (common) plugin and have the other two plugins extend that plugin? The only problem I see with this latter approach is that the common plugin doesn't have any sort of functionality available to the user (i.e., no UI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only problem I see with this latter approach is that the common plugin doesn't have any sort of functionality available to the user (i.e., no UI).

That's not unusual, and you've already come up with the right approach (although it's to `require` the new one as a dependency, not `extend` it if I'm reading your question right).

Comment: There is even a check box during the plugin project create 'This plug-in makes contributions to the UI' which you can leave unchecked for plugins which have no UI

Comment: In this case, how do l go about sharing the plugins on github? Would I use submodules or would I just mention the dependency to developers in a readme file?

Comment: It's good to keep in mind that you want the repository to be consumable *by* Eclipse in a pretty straightforward manner. That said, you can browse eclipse.org's own repositories at http://git.eclipse.org/c/ for ideas.

Comment: @greg-449 Ah I was looking at the plugin.xml/MANIFEST view and didn't see such a check box. It would be helpful to have it there as well.